# Input Text in EditText and display it in a second screen

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to create two screen UI. The first screen has an `editText` and a `Submit` button. The second screen has a `textView` to display text that would be entered in the first screen.

Here is the code I used, but the second screen does not show inputted text from the first screen.

MainActivity.kt [First Screen]:

```
package com.rishis.testinginputtext

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.rishis.testinginputtext.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        setContentView(binding.root)

    }

}
```

SecondActivity.kt [Second Screen]:

```
package com.rishis.testinginputtext

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.rishis.testinginputtext.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.rishis.testinginputtext.databinding.ActivitySecondBinding

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val oneBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        
        //textView refers to textView in secondActivity
        val textView = binding.textView
        //editText refers to EditText in mainActivity
        val editText = oneBinding.EditText
        
        textView.setText(editText.text.toString())

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

How should I display the text entered in the first screen to be shown in the second screen?

Comment: Get the text from `FirstActivity` pass it to the `SecondActivity` through intent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: intent and you can also bind using the EditText ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "putExtra" method to send the data to next activity,
and "getExtra" to get the data in next activity.

Please Refer the article-

https://medium.com/@haxzie/using-intents-and-extras-to-pass-data-between-activities-android-beginners-guide-565239407ba0

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple, you just need to use putExtras and getExtra in your activities

your first activity is looks like this:

```
 val textToPass = editText.text.toString()
 
 binding.button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY",textToPass)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

and in a second activity you can get the text by using a getStringExtra and which look like this

```
 val textToDislplay = intent.getStringExtra("SOME_KEY")
 textView.text = textToDisplay
```